# How to rename a file when move_uploaded_file in php?

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload, pdo

```
How to rename file when move_uploaded_file in php?
```

I tried to below code but override current image kindly help me how to rename.

```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo_img"]["tmp_name"],
        "../uploaded/" . $_FILES["logo_img"]["name"]
        );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO logo (logo_img, logo_name)VALUES(:logo_img, :logo_name)";
        $result = $db->queryPrepared($sql,array(
            ':logo_img' => $_FILES['logo_img']['name'],
            ':logo_name' => $_POST['logo_name']
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo_img"]["tmp_name"], "../uploaded/" . 'your_new_name.extension');
```

**Description**

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

**Parameters**

*filename*

```
The filename of the uploaded file.
```

*destination*

```
The destination of the moved file.
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @webdesign9 you got some advance with your problem?

Comment: Hi Adrian Cid Almaguer how to dynamically rename? mean how to call dynamic 'your_new_name'

Comment: @webdesign9 If you have an array you can loop through the array and change the name in each iteration.

Comment: @webdesign9 you got some advance?